# ADO.NET DataServices with Prism

Tags: silverlight, prism, wcf-data-services

I've start using prism with silverlight 3, but, we are trying to implement it to work with ADO.NET DataServices. The "DataServiceQuery" query type required to use with Silverlight, requires a Asyncronous call to be fired after the query. This will break ous Prism Pattern by what I can see.
Any ideas to get only the data of the query to use in Prism Pattern? Correct-me anyone if i'm wrong!

Comment: Well, the problem is that i'm not calling Data directly from the viewmodel, i'm calling instead from a service layer but silverlight requires me to make a callback in the service layer...That is what I was not getting right...
I wanted to return a observable collection from the service layer with the ado.net data services...Sorry I'm a bit nOOb at silverlight. Just too much to digest once ;)

Answer (score 1):

Making an Asynchronous call to your server doesn't break "Prism Pattern". When your view needs to query the server, its viewmodel fires an asynchronous request and provides a callback. Once callback is called, it handles the result and updates whatever properties it exposes to a view. This will result in view updating according to bindings you set up in your xaml.

Answer (score 0):

PL is exactly right.  There's really no patterns that Prism encourages that are incompatible with ADO.NET Data Services.  There are just a few things you should know.

Here's a small sample.  It's a little tricky... the complete event will sometimes fire outside of the UI thread, so you have to handle it with the dispatcher (at least in SL2 you did):

```
public class MyViewModel : BaseViewModel
{

     public Customer CustomerResult
     {
         ...
     }

     NorthwindEntities svcContext = null;
     public MyViewModel()
     {
            svcContext =
                new NorthwindEntities(new Uri("Northwind.svc", UriKind.Relative));

            DataServiceQuery<Customers> query =
                svcContext.Customers.Expand("Orders");

            // Begin the query execution.
                query.BeginExecute(WorkComplete, query);

     }



     private void WorkComplete(IAsyncResult result)
     {
          DataServiceQuery<Customers> query =
                    result.AsyncState as DataServiceQuery<Customers>;

          Customers returnedCustomer =
                    query.EndExecute(result).FirstOrDefault();

          //Execute with the dispatcher
          Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke( () =>
          {
               CustomerResult = returnedCustomer;
          });
     }
}
```

Of course there is no exception handling in here, but you get the picture hopefully.

Comment: Well, the beginInvoke Method is missing and at the momment i'm not figuring out why. but thanks for the reply

Comment: On the Dispatcher?  That doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Oh sorry... I forgot to include CurrentDispatcher.  I'm modifying the code.